# How to add a new node before the head of a linked list

Tags: java

I would like to ask: how to add a new node before the head of a linked list:
Here is my code:

```
   //   Definition for singly-linked list.
public class ListNode {
    int val; 
    ListNode next; 
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
    
    public void addAfter(ListNode thisnode, int x) {
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(x);
        if(thisnode == null) {
            //add before the head
            newNode.next = this;
            
        }//wrong here
        else {
            ListNode currentNext = thisnode.next;
            thisnode.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = currentNext;
        }
        return;
    }//done addAfter this node
    

    
}
```

For example, with the input list 2 100 300 800, `l.addAfter(null,500);` the output should be
500 2 100 300 800 but my output is still 2 100 300 800. Thank you.

Comment: Is creating a new `addBefore()` method an option? Because, in the context of a list node, it doesn't make sense to create the head using `addAfter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting before head would change the value of head. Which you can't do from inside the method.

```
public ListNode addAfter(ListNode thisnode, int x) {
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(x);
    if(thisnode == null) {
        //add before the head
        newNode.next = this;
        return newNode;    
     } else {
        ListNode currentNext = thisnode.next;
        thisnode.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = currentNext;
     }
     return this;
}
```

And the caller would call it like `l = l.addAfter(null,500);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make your code clear, readable and consistent. Here is what you asked for:

```
public class Node {

    private int value;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        next = null;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public class ListNode {

    private Node head;

    public ListNode(Node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public Node getHead(){
        return head;
    }

    // Here is your function
    public void insertBeforeHead(int value) {
        Node node = new Node(value);

        node.setNext(head); 
        head = node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// Node Class

```
 public class SinglyListNode {
        int val;
        SinglyListNode next;
        SinglyListNode(int x) { val = x; }
    }
```

//Singly Linked List class

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {
        private SinglyListNode head;
        public SinglyLinkedList() {
            head = null;
        }

        // add at beginning
        public void addAtBeginning(int value){
            SinglyListNode node = new SinglyListNode(value);
            if (head != null) {
                node.next = head;
            }
            head = node;
        }

        // print list
        public void printList(){
            System.out.println("printing linked list");
            SinglyListNode curr = head;
            while (curr != null){
                System.out.println(curr.val);
                curr = curr.next;
            }
        }

}
```

//main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList();
    linkedList.addAtBeginning(5);
    linkedList.addAtBeginning(6);
    linkedList.addAtBeginning(7);
    linkedList.printList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always make one head that is constant and add all the new elements after it.
Example:

> Head - Link1 - Link2 - Link3

Whenever you want to add newLink you can just add it in this manner.

> Head - newLink - Link1 - Link2 - Link3

In this way you head information is never lost and it reduce the chances of losing your entire list.

You can explore my codebase here which implements it.

> https://github.com/SayefReyadh/tutorials/tree/master/LinkedList-Bangla-Tutorial/LinkedListExample/src/linkedlistexample

The method is implemented as `insertFront` in `LinkedList.java`